# regex to replace multiple "AND NOT" conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I'm trying to use a regex to massage a string, read from. a text file, into an acceptable state for the Python3 JSON.loads() parser.
Trouble is my data (originally .ts-syntax objects) sometimes contains '"', other than as string-terminators, e.g.:

```
{
    value1: "blah",
    value2: 'foo"bar"',
}
```

The goal is for it to come out looking like (with inner double-quotes escaped),  so I'm trying to match *only* the "s inside another string (in this example,  those on the second line, but not those on the first):

```
{
    value1: "blah",
    value2: "foo\"bar\"",
}
```

(replacing the outer 's I can do in a separate step)
(I've already used separate re.sub() calls to add "s around keys, and remove ','s following the last k/v pairs in an element)

So far, my attempts so far have been to try matching *only* the "s that are *not* being used as string-terminators, so something along the lines of `r'(?:^: )"'` but *also* `r'"(?:^,)'`.
I've tried, without success, things such as:

- `re.match(r'(?:^: )"(?:^,)',  text)`
- `re.match(r'(?!^: )"(?!^,)',  text)`

Comment: So the result you would want is `value2: 'foo bar'`?

Comment: Is the object a dict or a string? What output do you expect? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Reformulated (and answered) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68306865/how-to-get-re-sub-to-add-a-single-backslash-between-group-placeholders**strong text**